# About HTML5 offline storage & cache for iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, html, cross-platform, browser-cache

Why HTML5 rocks now ? 
If just use one word to answer, I think probably it will be "cross-platform".

You can build products using HTML5 one time , distribute for different platform such as Web and iPad etc.

But after some research, I found that several problems with HTML5 family tech

> - Not robust : there are a lot of randomness , and not easy to control
> - Storgage limited : even no clear answer for max size (?) , and sure there are limitation of storage
> - Not best user interaction : compared with native iOS app

Any other problems you think ?

And if you are HTML5 guru,maybe you will correct some wrong understanding of mine.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem for me is that right now HTML5 is [not a standard](http://www.w3.org/2011/05/html5lc-faq.html). It's not even a complete specification.

But this has always been the problem with building web applications; everyone implements them to different degrees of completeness, and you have to be constantly vigilant of implementation variations.

If I end up having to maintain multiple versions of the same code for each browser anyway, I start to question whether the "it works everywhere" argument is even sound anymore.

Comment: 2014 is still far away. Lots of bad stuff for us web developers will happen before the HTML5 spec is "W3C Recommended".